# Why can't I call CTime::GetAsDBTIMESTAMP with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I create a new Visual C++ Win32 Project in Visual Studio 2012 - just a console application with a precompiled header. I add an include for `atltime.h` and three lines of code to `_tmain`:

```
// timeapp2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atltime.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CTime c = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
    DBTIMESTAMP t;
    c.GetAsDBTIMESTAMP(t);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it. It compiles fine.

I try the same thing in Visual Studio 2013. I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ATL::CTime::GetAsDBTIMESTAMP(struct tagDBTIMESTAMP &)const " (?GetAsDBTIMESTAMP@CTime@ATL@@QBE_NAAUtagDBTIMESTAMP@@@Z) referenced in function _wmain c:\tmp\timeapp\timeapp2\timeapp2.obj    timeapp2

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\tmp\timeapp\Debug\timeapp2.exe   1   1   timeapp2
```

This is a fresh installation of Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 2 taken from MSDN subscriber downloads. I have tried the same thing on two seperate machines, one running Windows 8.1 x64, and the other running Windows Server 2012 R2. Both fail to compile using Visual Studio 2013.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/906424/adding-a-call-to-ctime-getasdbtimestamp-produces-a-linker-error-but-i-can-call-other-ctime-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in Visual Studio 2013, and will be fixed in the next version. From the [Microsoft Connect page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/906424/adding-a-call-to-ctime-getasdbtimestamp-produces-a-linker-error-but-i-can-call-other-ctime-functions):

> Thanks for reporting this bug! I'm working on a fix now. This will be
>   resolved in the next release of VS.
>
> Artur Laksberg, VC++ Libraries Team

For now, we can use the following workaround which was posted on the Connect page:

```
CTime c = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
DBTIMESTAMP d;
COleDateTime(c.GetTime()).GetAsDBTIMESTAMP(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the ATL library.

(The following is for VS2008, sorry for my old environment - but I'd expect you can find the options in similar locations):

**When creating the project**, select "add general ATL headers"

**Alternatively** under Project Configuratrion / General, enable "Use of ATL" (either static or dynamic, dynamic gives a smaller executable but you need the respective ATL runtime in manifest and installed on the target)

---

**[edit]**
You can try to add the respective ATL lib manually to the linker (atl{s}{d}.lib, use 's' for static, 'd' for debug build). Haven't done ATL under VS2013 yet, so these are just "educated guesses".

---

If it's just this one call, you could also just use GetSystemTime, and then fill the DBTIMESTAMP structure.

(shameless plug: or, if you are coming from CTime, which is just a wrapper for _time64_t [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144159/Time-Format-Conversion-Made-Easy#More_Data) for conversion time_t --> SYSTEMTIME)

Comment: I can successfully call the function in a Visual Studio 2008 project (as well as a 2012 one), just not 2013. Selecting the 'ATL' checkbox under 'Add common header files for' makes no difference. One interesting thing though - there is no 'Use of ATL' option in my 2013 project properties dialog, just a 'Use of MFC'.

Comment: I tried adding atls.lib manually which didn't make a difference. I can call other `CTime` functions like `CTime::GetAsSystemTime` and the program compiles fine, it's just `GetAsDBTIMESTAMP` which is a problem. Because it's only that one function, the workaround looks good to me. I would still like to figure out why this is happening, so I'll go via MS support channels and see what they say. Thank you very much for your time.